# Prove that $F[x,y] / (y^2-x)$ is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that this quotient $F[x,y] / (y^2-x)$ is an integral domain.

The first idea I had is to show that $y^2 - x$ is prime in the polynomials with variable $x$ and $y$,however, this seems to be rather hard to verify.

Then I was thinking that would it be possible to construct some isomorphisms between this quotient ring and some integral domain, but I got stuck.

Comment: I would construct an isomorphism between this ring and $F[y]$. Can you imagine what the image of the coset of $x$ should be?

Comment: Alternatively, show that $y^2 - x$ is irreducible. What are the possible solutions for $(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f) = y^2 - x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x,y)=y^2-x$$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F[x][y]$ because it is a monic quadratic polynomial in $y$ with no roots in $\Bbb F(x)$. Equivalently, $f(x,y)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F[x,y]$ because $$g(x,y)\cdot h(x,y)=f(x,y)$$ implies one of $g(x,y),h(x,y)$, say $g(x,y)$, is a $\Bbb F[x][y]$ unit and thus a $\Bbb F[x,y]$ unit as well. Therefore, the ideal $\langle f(x,y)\rangle$ is a prime $\Bbb F[x,y]$ ideal and thus $\frac{\Bbb F[x,y]}{\langle f(x,y)\rangle}$ is an integral domain.

Comment: @Andy. In a unique factorization domain (UFD) there primes and irreducibles are one in the same. To prove the irreducibility of $f(x,y)$ I proved that given $\it{any}$ factorization $f(x,y)=g(x,y)\cdot h(x,y)$ at least one of $g,f$ must be a unit. With this I inferred that $f(x,y)$ is irreducible and thus prime because $\Bbb F[x,y]$ is a UFD. $\langle f(x,y)\rangle$ is a prime ideal because $f(x,y)$ is a prime element.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is very clear.